# How to invoke a method in a protected scope without reflection

Tags: java, oop

I would like to access a protected method from a variable.
For example,

A.java (a third-party library, like Spring's class)

```
package a;
public class A {
    protected void doA() {}
}
```

B.java (my own class)

```
package b;

public class B {
    public void doB(A a) {
       // how to invoke a.doA() here.
    }
}
```

As you can see from above, is there a way to access `a.doA()` in my own class withour using reflection?

Comment: The "without reflection" part of the question shows you already knew the answer. This might be an XY problem. Can you give us some idea of your broader objective? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: if a.A is a thrid-party library, and I want to invoke it by the class in b.B (my own class), how can I do ?

Comment: I don't think so, you can create a C.java which is under `a` package. And then it's possible to invoke A.doA() there.
For example,
`   package a;
    public class C {
        public static void doA(A a) {
            a.doA();
        }
    }
`
and then you can use C.doA(a); to invoke it in your own class (b.B)